# Imagen from Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm trying to get the data from a canvas and set the src attribute of a img element. The problem here is that, the canvas has a background image setted with css, not with canvas methods. Is there any way or method to extract the background image so the toDataURL method could catch it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is a solid reason why you are not drawing the background image to the canvas itself so I can offer you this solution:

- Draw the background-image to a second canvas element positioned below the first canvas.
- When you want to take the canvas data and use it create a third canvas (no need to attach it to the DOM or make it visible.
- Draw the background canvas onto it and then draw the main canvas on top.
- Take the data from the third canvas.
- Voila.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, there is a solid reason indeed! Thanks, I'll try